# Draw UIView with bezier path

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

How to draw a view like image below

[image: Desing]

I want to **UIView** like annotation view in picture,
I know get image from designer and assign it in **UIImageView** and i don't want do that way and pop over presentation also no need.

I wanted to do this with UIView by 
**UIBezierPath**
or some other other way..

Help would be appreciated and Thanks in advance!!

Comment: 4 corners are rounded using bazer path but not down arrow draw using bazer path

Comment: so you use image for down arrow

Comment: is this possible

Comment: Not possible as you wanted.

Comment: Did you try to draw it with bezier path? Show us what you've tried so we can help from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
class PopUpView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let width: CGFloat = rect.width
        let height: CGFloat = rect.height

        let radius: CGFloat = 8
        let arrowRadius: CGFloat = 4

        let arrowWidth: CGFloat = 24
        let arrowHeight: CGFloat = 18

        let startingPoint = CGPoint(x: radius, y: 0)
        let upperRightCenter = CGPoint(x: width - radius, y: radius)
        let bottomRightCenter = CGPoint(x: width - radius, y: height - radius - arrowHeight)
        let bottomLeftCenter = CGPoint(x: radius, y: height - radius - arrowHeight)
        let upperLeftCenter = CGPoint(x: radius, y: radius)

        let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: startingPoint)

        path.addArc(withCenter: upperRightCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)

        path.addArc(withCenter: bottomRightCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 90.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)

        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: (width + arrowWidth)/2 + arrowRadius, y: height + arrowRadius - arrowHeight), radius: arrowRadius, startAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 225.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)

        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height - arrowRadius), radius: arrowRadius, startAngle: 45.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 135.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)

        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: (width - arrowWidth)/2 - arrowRadius, y: height + arrowRadius - arrowHeight), radius: arrowRadius, startAngle: 315.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)

        path.addArc(withCenter: bottomLeftCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 180.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)

        path.addArc(withCenter: upperLeftCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 180.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)

        path.close()

        UIColor.gray.setFill()
        UIColor.clear.setStroke()

        path.fill()
        path.stroke()
    }

}

extension Int {
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(M_PI) * CGFloat(self) / 180.0
    }
}
```

Basically I subclassed a UIView, overidden the drawRect method and used UIBezierPath to create a similar shape. You may want to change the values I used to suite your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i will try and let u know

Comment: drawRect method not calling at all, can you show us usage of code or how should i call class in controller?

Comment: @karthikeyan you just need to subclass your UIView with the PopUpView class. It is working in my app.

Comment: moreover if after adding your view to superView if drawRect is still not called you can add view.setNeedsDisplay(), this forces the drawRect method to be called

Comment: This answer would be much better if the relevant code was actually posted in the answer. Don't make people click a link to see code.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for reminding, let me add the code here.

Comment: @Aakash is there way to do this without subclassing

Comment: @karthikeyan I don't know a better way to do this without subclassing, as far as I know it is only done by overridding the drawRect method.

Comment: its fine i did it without subclassing thanks for your time.